# Is it possible that Dialog can works with combitation of rounded corners and DayNight theme at same time in Android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, material-components

**CURRENT UPDATE:** Still not solved!

**Question:**
*Is it possible that Dialog/AlertDialog/AlertDialogBuilder/MaterialAlaertDialogBuilder can works with combitation of rounded corners and DayNight theme at same time in Android?*

I tired a lot, but I don't think that it is possible. Only one thing will work.

You can suggest me using material library.

Rounded corner with theme style is really possible in Dialog?

**Code:**

```
public void showFeedbackDialog(int code) {
        exitCode = code;
        dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.dialogBoxStyle);

        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_feedback_dialog, null);
        name = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.feedback_name);
        email = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.feedback_email);
        content = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.feedback_content);
        TextView nameError = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.nameError);
        emailError = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.emailError);
        feedbackError = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.feedbackError);
        progressBar = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        skip = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.skip);
        submit = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button_positive);
        cancel = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button_negative);

        dialog.setContentView(dialogView);

        if (code == 101) {
            skip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (code == 102) {
            skip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (checkValidation()) {
                            addFeedbackData();
                        }
                    }
                });

                cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (code == 101) {
                            FeedbackDialog.this.dialog.dismiss();
                            FixedCategorySingleton.getInstance().setNullObject();
                            activity.finishAffinity();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    }
```

**row_feedback_dialog**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_positive_round"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/row_progress_bar"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <TextView
            style="@style/dialog_hint_textview_style"
            android:text="Please share your Feedback"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                style="@style/hint_textview_style"
                android:text="@string/name" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/feedback_name"
                style="@style/edit_text_style"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/nameError"
            layout="@layout/row_error_textview" />

       <!-- <EditText
            android:id="@+id/feedback_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorIconLightGray"
            android:hint="Name (Optional)"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="?attr/textcolor" />-->



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                style="@style/hint_textview_style"
                android:text="@string/email" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/feedback_email"
                style="@style/edit_text_style"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/emailError"
            layout="@layout/row_error_textview" />

       <!-- <EditText
            android:id="@+id/feedback_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorIconLightGray"
            android:hint="Email (Optional)"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="?attr/textcolor" />-->


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                style="@style/hint_textview_style"
                android:text="What would you like to tell us?" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/feedback_content"
                style="@style/edit_text_style"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
        </LinearLayout>


       <!-- <EditText
            android:id="@+id/feedback_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorIconLightGray"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="What would you like to tell us?"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:textColor="?attr/textcolor" />-->

        <include
            android:id="@+id/feedbackError"
            layout="@layout/row_error_textview" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/skip"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor"
                        android:text="@string/skip_caps"
                        android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_negative"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor"
                        android:text="@string/cancel"
                        android:textColor="?attr/textcolor" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_positive"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor"
                        android:text="@string/submit"
                        android:textColor="?attr/textcolor" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**style**

```
  <style name="dialogBoxStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:background">?attr/backgroundcolor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/textcolor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">?attr/textcolor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?attr/textcolor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">?attr/textcolor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">?attr/textcolor</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
        <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">?attr/textcolor</item>
    </style>
```

If I don't use theme then everything will work fine. corner are coming in rounded shape because of getWindow line. 
But, in my app I'm using theme also.

I request you to help me, I finally created this account because of I need solution.

**UPDATE:**

tried with material library, not giving any effect

Comment: Exactly what do you need? Round corner with theme ? What is your output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57843956/7666442

Comment: @yes Round corner with theme?, but I can not change what is inside theme.

Comment: @Piyush yes, rounded corner with theme

Comment: Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-make-custom-dialog-with-rounded-corners-in-android)

Comment: @NileshRathod, I checked that link. but I used so many properties textColor, textColorSecondary n all. So will it work same?

Comment: @PriyankaSingh Yes. It can also customize the colors using the colors. Check [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md#styles)

Comment: @Piyush, in that example, parent is different, that is not wroking with theme. I tried it.

Comment: try this one: make xml file rounded shape and this line of code dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

Comment: @ViralPatel Already tried. problem is when I add style which parent is (Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert) this, that changed rounded corner to square.

Comment: use the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` from the material library. I guess with this u need to use the MaterialThemes as the default theme for this.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md

Comment: If you still want to use your own background u need to set the windowBackgound attribute to make it work.

Comment: @PembaTamang Dear, I don't want to use library in my project. And how can I  set the windowBackgound attribute?

Comment: Share your output snapshot

Comment: that is the new material library from google https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/

windowbackgound is set in the styles
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23207466/8528047

Comment: @Piyush wait I'll sent it

Comment: chech this one: https://www.journaldev.com/19352/android-daynight-theme-night-mode

Comment: @Piyush https://photos.app.goo.gl/GDqVNDzoFC2AHgH38

Comment: @ViralPatel Dear I know how to works with theme. I carefully checked your theme. There is no such combitation with rounded corners and dayNight theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md#alert-dialogs) included in the [Material Components 
library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).
Use the method  `.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout)` to inflate your custom layout.

Something like:

```
 new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this,
            R.style.MyThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog)
              .setTitle("Dialog")
              .setView(R.layout.dialog_layout)
              .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
              .setNegativeButton("Skip", null)
              .show();
```

Then use the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** to define your shape and apply **rounded corners** (it requires v.1.1.0).

```
 <!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    ...
  </style>


  <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">#00f</item>
  </style>

  <!-- Rounded corners -->
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Also you can use the attribute **`materialThemeOverlay`** to override the default style/color defined in your app theme, without changing it for all components.

Something like:

```
<style name="MyThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyAlThemeOverlay</item>
    ...
</style>

  <style name="MyAlThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

Also the Material Components library supports the [**DayNight theme**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Dark.md).
Your app theme has just to inherit from **`Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`**.

Something like:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

or:

`res/values/themes.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <!-- ...  -->
</style>
```

`res/values-night/themes.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

Without changing your code, the `AlertDialog` inherits from the app theme.

Comment: will it work for day night theme without using manually if/else condition and no need to create separate styles for day n night?

Comment: @PriyankaSingh Yes. The Material Components library supports [DayNight theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Dark.md).

Comment: @PriyankaSingh Just tried. AlertDialog has a full support for DayNight theme without any changes in the code. Answer updated.

Comment: First of all you need to use a [Material Theme in your App theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) (not AppCompat). Then check the constructor of MaterialAlertDialog (you have to pass the style if you don't want to change globally) and then check the shapeAppearanceOverlay attribute (use the latest 1.1.0-alpha10).

Comment: Please clear me: Should I use MaterialAlertDialogBuilder with alert dialog because I want to show three button with set on showListener. Also theme and rounded corners both will work? if yes, please change your answer according to my question, because, just now I tried and replease my code with MaterialAlertDialogBuilder, theme and round corner both are not giving me effect. Please help and let me accept your answer.

Comment: I tried accroding to your last comment and copied your code too. please check my above comment

Comment: @PriyankaSingh The `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` helps you to build an `AlertDialog`   with a Material Theme and features like shaping. And yes, it works with app theme and you can apply the rounded corners. (For example try an empty app with a very simple Dialog like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501488/android-alertdialog-with-rounded-corners/57843956#57843956)]. And the google library supports DayNight theme by default.